# accepting Xcode license without having whole Xcode

Tags: xcode, license

I have installed XCL(Xcode command line) through `xcode-select --install` therefore, not whole Xcode installed.

and I can see the path

```
xcode-select -print-path
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

However, I need to accept the license, but it complains that the Xcode is not installed

```
sudo xcodebuild -license
xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance
```

If you recommend me to install whole Xcode first ? should I uninstall XCT first ? and if so how !

Answer (score 1):

Running xcodebuild requires you to have the whole Xcode (GUI) package installed.

Instead run this command:

```
 sudo xcrun cc
```

It will allow you to accept the license from the CLI.

Comment: I have the same problem. This solution does not work. I get the error "clang: error: no input files"

Comment: Perhaps you’re on a newer system like High Sierra?

Comment: I am using High Sierra. Does this solution not work with 10.13?

Comment: Perhaps, I don't know. The question was about El Capitan, which is the version I tested the answer on.